# Flex-box two boxes wrap when scaling window browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

We have four children in one parent. And I want to make effect which you see on the picture.

```
<article class="parent">
<figure class="child">
    <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption">
        <p>description</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="child">
    <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption">
        <p>description</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="child">
    <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption">
        <p>description</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="child">
    <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption">
        <p>description</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</article>
```

The child have one constant parameter width: 300px;

But we cannot edit the html (+div).

We can use only CSS for that thing. **Is that possible?**

[image: example in picture]

My English is poor sry :)

Comment: Media queries maybe?

Comment: Disable `flex-wrap: wrap` in the main rule. In a media query that is set to a breakpoint where the screen width allows only two items, restore `flex-wrap: wrap`. With this method you control where wrapping occurs, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? https://codepen.io/jnnkm/pen/jVwZrX

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 800px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1000px)  {

  .parent {
    width: initial; 
  }
}
```

Comment: i believe he looks more for something like this https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dORdZR :)

Answer (score 0):

Good evening The Agropl!

Maybe this is something that can help you in the right direction - im still new to using flexbox, so if this can be done more correct, feel free to correct me. :)

http://codepen.io/andreastherkildsen/pen/pNeajo

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <h3>1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
     <h3>1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
     <h3>1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
     <h3>1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum,</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and the style

```
.flex-container{
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items:  baseline;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.flex-item{
  background: tomato;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item h3{
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.flex-item p{
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 50px; 
}

@media all and (max-width: 1230px) {
  .flex-item{
    padding-right:100px;
  }
}
```